# Swap mouse button on linux and MacOS

Tags: c, linux

In Windows, there is a Win32 system call SwapMouseButton to swap the primary button of the mouse. Now, I need such system call or way to swap mouse button on Linux and MacOS.
By this, I want to make one-click mouse button swapping application.

How would you do this in C?

Comment: @boj: I cannot find any answer related to it in [link](http://superuser.com). Also, I want code in C due to this I considered this more suitable for this forum.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read last line of your question before flagging it and adding the comment. I've edited my comment to ask if you've tried anything.

Comment: @boj: Currently, in Linux, I am looking for system call to achieve this. I look the source code of Wine (Windows Emulator) for implementation of SwapMouseButton. But it has not helped so much.

Comment: May I know the reason why it is voted down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a *system call* to do this. The mouse is operated by the X system, not by the kernel.
You can run this shell command `xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1"` to swap the left and right buttons, and run `xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3"` to restore the original settings..
You can also use [`execve`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) to execute the above command from *C*.

#### EDIT

The [`system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) function is actually more easy to use:

```
system("xmodmap -e \"pointer = 3 2 1\""); // for swapping buttons
system("xmodmap -e \"pointer = 1 2 3\""); // for restoring functionality
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this work on Mac systems also? Is there any way to achieve this through C (without execve)? Also, I need something like to  toggle the mouse button. For which there is query required. Is it possible using xmodmap.

Comment: `xmodmap` works on apple too, see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/xmodmap.1.html)

Comment: What do you mean by *toggle*? That the original mapping is restored automatically after the swapped button is clicked once? You may need [this SO question] to listen to mouse events in your app.

Comment: Toggle means if primary button is left, then right should become primary button and vice-versa. For this, I think, first a query is required (to check if the button is swapped), if buttons are not swqpped, then swap the button.

Comment: xmodmap can't do that. You will need to listen to mouse events and swap buttons with `xmodmap` when needed..

Comment: Does it require a logout or restart? It does not seem to work on Mac OS (Mountain Lion 10.7.4).

Comment: What exactly? The `xmodmap` or `system` call? And are there any error messages?

Comment: sorry, posted wrong button sequence in `system` example.. answer edited.

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't have a mac in my posession so i can't check why.. When i get to mac i will check and post back..

Comment: Reason might be that this is for X11 systems and Mac OS X may not running on X11 by default.

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea whether the output is reliable/portable, but `xmodmap -pp` reports the current pointer button mappings, so depending on your use-case you *may* be able to use that for toggling the state.

e.g. As a shell command, on my system, the following toggles (and reports) the first three buttons between `1 2 3` and `3 2 1` (well, it makes an assumption, but it's good enough for my requirement).

```
(xmodmap -pp | grep -q "\b1\b  *\b1\b") && xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1" || xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3"; xmodmap -pp | head -7
```